# Where do the device option values beginning with "Monitor-xyz" come from in xorg.conf?

Tags: debian, drivers, graphics, radeon, amd

Trying to install prop drivers for my Radeon HD6850 card on crunchbang (debian-based linux).

Followed [these instructions](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Debian) for install from repo and used aticonfig instead of amdconfig to create an initial xorg.conf file. This didn't give any options though and on the web I see countless references to "Monitor-CRT1" and "Monitor-DFPx" without any explanation as to their significance or where they got them from.

I have a dual screen 'shared' desktop. The initial aticonfig left me with a single monitor default config. How do I come up with a config that mirrors my setup?

Running X.org 1.10

Comment: Most probably autoprobed data from the connected monitors.

Comment: can you expand on how to do that?

Comment: When X starts, it probes for a lot of information on the graphics card and connected monitors. When creating a `xorg.conf` file, this information is dumped into it. Otherwise you'd have to trawl all over Google and the manufacturer's sites, and assorted other random sites, to find the required data. That was **the** way to do it, way back then. Only there was _no_ Google... and to add more fun, bad configuration could fry the monitor.

Comment: I didn't have an xorg.conf file until I ran aticonfig?

Comment: I suppose so, yes.